# Any limitations or risks to use Three20 for commercial application development?

Tags: ios, frameworks, open-source, licensing, three20

In iOS open source community, Three20 is so so so awesome one.

It provides a lot powerful extensions from UI to network ...

My question is any limitations or risks to use it for commercial apps dev ?

Thanks for share any experience or considerations for using three20

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing or legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139804/can-licensing-questions-ever-be-on-topic) for details, and the [help] for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you asking about licensing?  As far as that goes, Three20 is licensed under the Apache license.

Apache license: http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Three20 license: https://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/LICENSE

Or are you more interested in whether bugs get fixed timely, community support, etc?  If so, I've generally found it to be pretty well-supported, although the documentation isn't great.  Installing it/the size of the dependency used to be an issue, but this has been addressed by breaking the libraries up into chunks and also scripting adding Three20 as a depdendency. The code is certainly solid as is evidenced by the fact that Facebook's iOS app is written on top of it.

Hope that helps

Comment: yes,the license is commercial friendly totally.  Thanks for your comments. what I really care is that I am afraid that something can not be implemented if following the Three20 philosophy.

Comment: Including Three20 shouldn't restrict any other parts of the iOS SDK.  If there is something that can not be implemented using Three20 philosophy, you can use the rest of the iOS.  The only harm it could bring that I can think of would be increasing the footprint of your app.  Any specific concerns?

Comment: footprint ? what is that mean ? Another concern is navigation model. About passing parameters, no limitations ? Is that easy to pass specific objects such as UIImage etc ?

Comment: By footprint, I just mean size of the final download of your app.  In regards to passing parameters, it is easy to pass objects using the URL-based navigation.  See "Native Parameters" section in http://three20.info/article/2010-10-06-URL-Based-Navigation